# Sealed class generics in kotlin not related to inner classes

Tags: kotlin

I want to have an `ApiResponse` with some generic type to know what type will contain in case of success, something like:;

I mean, what I pretend is:

```
sealed class ApiResponse<T> {
  class Success<T>(body: T)
}

fun getUsers(): ApiResponse<List<User>>
```

And then when I call `getUsers` I know that it may contain a `ApiResponse.Success<List<User>>`.

**But** `T` from `ApiResponse<T>` is not related to `Success<T>` since I can write it like:

```
sealed class ApiResponse<NotUsed> {
  class Success<T>(body: T)
}
```

And then I create a function that returns an `ApiResponse` like:

```
fun getUsers(): ApiResponse
```

I dont know which kind of object that response may contain if it was a success.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Success` class isn't related to your `ApiResponse` class in any way other than being scoped inside of it. If you want the `Success` to be an `ApiResponse`, you should do something like this, which will also relate the generic types:

```
sealed class ApiResponse<T> {
    class Success<T>(body: T) : ApiResponse<T>()  // Success extends ApiResponse
}
```

Note that they only have to be in the same file, not necessarily nested (since Kotlin 1.1), so the following will also work:

```
sealed class ApiResponse<T>

class Success<T>(body: T) : ApiResponse<T>()  // Success extends ApiResponse
```